# Calculating the diagonal Sobel operator

Tags: math, image-processing, computer-vision, derivative, sobel

I was trying to calculate the diagonal (bottom left to top right) Sobel operator but couldn't manage to do it. I know what it should look like, but getting there im not able to.

So thanks in advance if some kind soul can explain it.

I already tryed to synthesise it out of the horizontal and vertical Sobel operators, but got stuck in multiple wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x and y derivatives together form the gradient vector. Using the Sobel operator you can compute these two derivatives.

Projecting the gradient vector onto a unit vector you can find the directional gradient. Your desired direction corresponds to the unit vector `[sqrt(2), -sqrt(2)]`. The projection is a dot product. Thus, your desired derivative image corresponds to:

```
dx = sobel(img)
dy = sobel(img)
out = sqrt(2)*dx - sqrt(2)*dy
```

Knowing that the Sobel operator is applied with a convolution, and that the convolution is associative and linear, we can see that the operations above  correspond to a single convolution with a kernel formed by `sqrt(2)*sobel_x - sqrt(2)*sobel_y`. We can compute this kernel:

```
         0    2.8284    2.8284
   -2.8284         0    2.8284
   -2.8284   -2.8284         0
```

Of course you could choose to normalize the kernel differently, the magnitude of the Sobel operator is wrong anyway. So you could instead use for example

```
     0     1     1
    -1     0     1
    -1    -1     0
```

Comment: Thanks, that 100% answered my question. even though im confused why it got closed, because theres no answer to this, being found anywhere else. Anyway, huge thank you, helped a lot.